# find matching rows excel formula or vba

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I have an excel file with two sheets and identical formats on each. I need to search vertically down the sheet and find the matching row on the other sheet on the and return the value of a cell from the that row, but only if the entire row matches.

I tried could not find an exact answer for this. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Use Vlookup function

Comment: The row spans A - I and there are about 100 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it works for a limited data set (in this case rows 1 to 10):

```
=INDEX(B!$I$1:$I$10,MATCH(A!A1&A!B1&A!C1&A!D1&A!E1&A!F1&A!G1&A!H1&A!I1,INDEX(B!$A$1:$A$10&B!$B$1:$B$10&B!$C$1:$C$10&B!$D$1:$D$10&B!$E$1:$E$10&B!$F$1:$F$10&B!$G$1:$G$10&B!$H$1:$H$10&B!$I$1:$I$10,0),0))
```

Data structure in sheets A and B is identical. The formula returns the value from Sheet B, column I from the rows where the values in columns A to I are identical in both sheets.

It should be fine with 100 rows, but don't do this with whole column references.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is, in a third sheet, populate the range A1:I~100 with:

```
 =IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1,"")
```

and J1 down to suit with:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A1:I1)
```

Filter ColumnJ to select `0` and pick you required values from those rows.

Comment: it needs to search down all the colunms for the matching row they may not always be in the same order from sheet to sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming worksheets are named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` *(change as required)*, their data structure is identical and data ranges are `A1:I100` in each *(change as required)*.

In a third sheet enter this `FormulaArray` in `A1` and copy till last record (`A100`)

*Enter the FormulaArray pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{`...`}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

```
=SUM( ( Sheet1!$A1:$I1 = Sheet2!$A$1:$I$100 ) * 1 ) = COLUMNS( $A1:$I1 )
```

Then in `B1` enter this formula copy till `J1` then till last record (`B2:J100`)

```
=IF( $A1 , Sheet1!A1 ,"" )
```

You can also enter this formula in `Sheet1!J1` and copy till last record:

```
=SUM( ( $A1:$I1 = Sheet2!$A$1:$I$100 ) * 1 ) = COLUMNS( $A1:$I1 )
```

Or enter this formula in `Sheet2!J1` and copy till last record:

```
=SUM( ( $A1:$I1 = Sheet1!$A$1:$I$100 ) * 1 ) = COLUMNS( $A1:$I1 )
```